# VueJs dev tools panel not showing

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, vue-resource

I started using [vue dev-tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) in my application but it is not visible when in developer mode in Chrome. I tried various solutions found on the dev-tools github page and in other places on the web, but no luck. Below are the things i have done/tried to get it to display.

1. Enabled `allow access to file URL’s option` in the chrome extension
2. Added `Vue.config.debug = true;` `Vue.config.devtools = true;` just before new Vue({})
3. Added non-minified versions of VueJS file
4. Also I am using Chrome latest version: 55.0.2883.87.

I do get the following message when I click on the chrome extension
[image]

Except the panel is not actually showing.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: please provide sceenshot of your devtools

Comment: I contributed to vue-devtools-3.0 so I was following closely to make sure nothing I did broke anything. This is likely the issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/218

Comment: unfortunately i still have the same issue . I tried different way to get the chrome extension . By cloning the repo building the dev-tools app . But still no luck . I don't see the vue dev-tools panel.

Comment: Any chance you could mark my answer below as the correct one?

Comment: Best answer for me. Thanks!!

Comment: This is how my experience with it began: The devtool wasn't functioning when the build was set to prod mode. Initially, I was running my application on my local machine, and after fixing some bugs, I deployed the build using "npm run build" to the production environment. However, upon trying to run the application locally again, I found that the Vue dev tools had stopped working. To resolve the issue, I deleted the "dist" directory and restarted the application in dev mode, which allowed everything to start working again.

Comment: @Nicolas What answer is that? This is a question.

Answer (score 100):

I could not get the Vue icon to be active on the menu bar, however I was able to get the Vue tab to show in the Chrome developer tools. Try the following:

- Close the Chrome developer tools window
- Hard refresh the browser
- Re-open the developer tools window and look for the Vue tab

The icon in the toolbar might still indicate that it cannot detect Vue, but the tab should be visible in the Chrome developer tools.

Comment: I just closed and re-open Chrome, it was enough. And thanks for the tip.

Comment: In my case, the Vue DevTools icon was illuminated and detected Vue.js, but the Vue tab was absent from Chrome's DevTools panel. Closing DevTools, hard-refreshing the page, and re-opening DevTools allowed me to see the Vue panel, but none of the Vue functionality was present (e.g., no components detected). I had to close Chrome completely and relaunch it, and then everything worked as expected. Odd.

Answer (score 27):

I had this same issue, I was using minified vue from cdn "vue.min.js" .Then I removed that and used non-minified vue. Then I reloaded browser and reopened console and the vue tab was there.

Comment: Oh thanks man. This was the only solution that worked for me. saved my day.

Comment: This works for me. I'm just using the cdn setup.

Comment: Thanks!! it's working.

Answer (score 18):

For me, I was running a local HTML file. By default, Chrome blocks extensions from working on local files.

- 3-dot menu -> More Tools -> Extensions
- Find the Vue extension, click details and change turn on the setting "Allow access to file URLs:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBgla.png)

- close & reopen chrome

Comment: Found that I did NOT need to close and reopen Chrome. Got by with a hard reset.

Answer (score 12):

Also found today that if you have an ad blocker installed that this also stops Vue Devtools from running properly.

Answer (score 9):

Closing the file tab and reopening it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

- Restart many times Google Chrome
- Don't use min file
- And add before new vue instantiation:

  ```
  Vue.config.devtools = true;
  ```

Answer (score 6):

chrome developer tools should be close before enabling the vue dev tools extention...
(if chrome devtools is open, close chrome development tools and re-open)

Comment: yes, this fix it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just do a "hard reload" for a few times. On windows: SHIFT + F5. 
On Mac: CMD + SHIFT + R.

Comment: Hard reload (shift + cmd + r on mac) and reload (close and open) chrome inspect solve this. (yes in 2020)

Answer (score 3):

Use the devtools beta for Vue 3. And always check if your Vue app mounted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** add `vue.js devtools` as an extension  from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en)

**step 2:** After adding `vue.js devtools`, close your browser.

**Step 3:** Open your browser and open your html page.

**Step 4:** click right side of your mouse and select `inspect` and try to find `Vue`.

**Note:** If you didn't added the CDN of vue.js, then add these line to your html file.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
```

Comment: Does not work. Only Beta version works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable **Allow access to file URLs** from Vue extension and then hard refresh your page with **Shift + F5**
It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

(For Firefox Browser) If the add-ons 'Vue.js devtools' is added in browser..Just click on Inspect Element (or press F12) and there is a tab of Vue along with Inspector, Console, Network etc. Click on that Vue tab and enjoy debugging.

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked was:

1. Inside DevTools, Open Command Menu `Control+Shift+P (Windows / Linux) or Command+Shift+P (Mac)`
2. Select "reload DevTools"
3. Now it shows in the DevTools

Comment: Control+Shift+P is the shortcut for the print dialog in Chrome?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked for me using the **edge** browser

Answer (score 1):

Hard Reload, help me.

Open devtools -> right click on reload button -> Hard Reload

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to view vue devtool in the production environment.

```
Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.
```

[image]

So although it did say that vue is detected on this page but then it also says that Devtool is not available in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just do hard reload and close development console then reopen it.

Comment: I didn't down vote this, I think the reason it was down voted is because it looks like a copy of my answer which was made a few months before...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't use the production CDN. The only way that make it work for me is to use the VueJS dev version.

Development : [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me periodically, pretty annoying because there seems to be no cause.

- Go to Chrome browser extensions
- Remove the Vue DevTools extension
- Add it back again
- Hard refresh your page

---

Chrome - Version 71.0.3578.98

MacOS Mojave 10.14

VueJS 2.5.21

Answer (score 0):

1. close the chrome app
2. re-run development server
3. re-open chrome app
4. open localhost
5. press F12 (to open development tools)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe obvious but the Vue panel is not available when in incognito mode. In this case, the Vue icon is not visible either.

Enter chrome://extensions in the address bar and click on *Details* for Vue.js devtools. Scroll down to "Allow in Incognito" and switch to *On*.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Can you add any information, e. g. for what to do when incognito mode is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using vue3, uninstall Vue devtool extension and install the beta version.
you can install it for chrome from the below link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg

Comment: If just adding information to an existing answer, consider leaving a comment instead of posting a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

In **@Daryn** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44766305/860099) he mention that he has problems witch vue icon - here is solution to this part of running vue extension on chrome which in the same time also solve OP problem for me:

During plugin installation for short moment in upper right chrome corner the VUE ICON appears with message (screenshot is not my):

[image]

And CRITICAL is to click right button on that icon (without close that message!) and choose "PIN" (it pin to extensions icons bar) - if you not do it - then you will never see that icon again (which is mistake). After that shut down and reopen chrome. And now in you page with vue, this icon should have green colors (you can click on it) and click right button on some page element (or on screen center) and choose "Inspect" to see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can go to settings then go to preferences then look for persistence then enable local overrides, sorry my english is not good

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps but make sure to refer to app.js in your view file you are rendering in your current path. Laravel example from view file: `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

This way the vue extension starded working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
npm run watch
```

or

```
npm run dev
```

otherwise you can not see Vue Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Chrome worked for me

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you have the extension installed.
- If you are on a live website, there is a good chance it's using a
  production build of Vue.
  Use a non-minified, non-prod version of Vue on CDN
  Set the **VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS** environment variable for Vue 3 when using a bundler like Webpack (more info).
- Try closing the devtools pane, refreshing the page and opening the
  devtools pane again.
- Try restarting the browser or the computer.
- If you have multiple versions of the Vue devtools installed, it's
  recommended to disable/remove the others.
- Try disabling other devtools extensions like React devtools.
- Look for errors in the browser Console.
- Update your project dependencies.
- Even if the Vue logo in the toolbar is gray and says "Vue not
  detected", open your browser devtools and check if the Vue tab is
  showing up anyaway.

**more details bellow down link**

["devtools don't Show Up" GUIDE](https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/faq.html#the-vue-devtools-don-t-show-up)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I already had a debugger attached by running Chrome via a VSCode launch.json.
It seems that by being able to debug in VSCode you also lose the possibility to connect to this Vue instance via the Devtools.

Killing the Chrome that was openened by the VSCode launch configuration, opening a new one and navigating to the running Vue instance then fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

(Microsoft Edge)

In my case, the "Vue" text is hidden on toolbar but I can still click.

See the mouse highlight beside the "Detached Elements" tab 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

don't forget about

```
npm run dev
```

(or something like in your project)

And then try advisions from first answers

Comment: that does not answer the question, as it's mentioned that vue is running at all

Comment: Heh, I just made this mistake

Comment: Great, that you found it, but again, this doesn't answer the question and in the question it's made clear that npm was running. So this answer is like "yes, me too". Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer